# Как удалённо управлять компьютером с возможностью удалённого включения и выключения?

Tags: wifi, доступ, kvm

Допустим у меня есть WiFi сеть, ноутбук и системник . Могу ли я удаленно управлять системником через ноутбук . Включать , выключить и использовать его? 
Или такое возможно только через проводные kvm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для включения/выключения есть технология [WoL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN), по умолчанию выключена в bios, а софт-ов для управления ПК много разных, выбрать есть с чего )